# Subform Page reload and textbox change if else

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am a beginner I just wanted to ask for advice I am have a subform with textfield named txt1 it will reload and get the value of the parent form selected selectbox value. So everytime the mainform change the selection of selectbox in the it will reload the subform and txt1  will get the value of the selectbox  I am trying to implement a condition under the subform that everytime the value of txt1 changed after subform form reload it will implement a condition when the value is equal particular string

in the subform my code is like this but it doesnt do anything it dont do the condition. I will really appreciate any advice thank you

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

     var d = $('#txt1').val();
     if d=='All'{
     //do something
     }else{
}
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Right now, your if statement is only executing once, when the document first loads. What you need to do is, in the same document.ready function, add a listener that listens for a change on the select, and place your if statement in that function. Something like: $( "select" ).change(function() {...place IF here...});